# Tailwind in my Next-js project don´t charge/update the styles

Tags: next.js, tailwind-3

I´m doing a Next-js project and when I put the tailwind clases (ml-auto, md:hidden...) some of the styles, but not all don´t charge in the webpage.

I´ve tried to update my tailwind (npm i tailwind) but don´t work. The only thing works is add the class in the layout.css, file inside ".next" folder. But when I do commit and push the classes that I added disapper. The tailwind classes that don´t work, aren´t in layout.css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.